# Ubuntu won't boot when set to boot from UEFI

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi

I am not particularly computer wise so please bear with me and talk to me like an idiot...

I have freshly installed Ubuntu with no other OS present (wiped the hard drive in the process) and set it to boot from UEFI. When I boot, the Ubuntu logo comes up but it hangs on this screen and will not go any further. If I set my BIOS to boot Legacy then spam F12 to get a one-time boot menu then select UEFI boot, it runs fine...

Any ideas or suggestions welcome!

Comment: please post a screenshot

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the BIOS/UEFI... Maybe try updating the BIOS?

Comment: Chances are you're running into a hardware initialization problem, and activating the BIOS/CSM/legacy support slightly modifies the hardware initialization. "Black screen" problems like yours were very common a couple of years ago, seemed to fade away a bit over time, but have made a recurrence in reporting frequently recently. See [this question and its answers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076) for more on the subject. Solutions are highly hardware-specific.

Comment: Try pressing Escape when you get stuck on the Ubuntu Logo Screen. This brings up the boot process and shows what package is causing issue. Maybe post a screenshot of it here?